# How can I multiattach EBS volumes to more than one EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

For using a cluster filesystem like OCFS or sharing read-only data between machines, one needs to attach the same SAN volume/LUN to multiple servers at the same time.

How can I do that with EBS volumes on Amazon EC2 ?

console.aws.amazon.com seems not to allow attaching an already attached volume and the Amazon documentation doesn't contain "multiattach".
Perhaps I need another keyword to search for ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you can do it with Provisioned IOPS io1 volumes.

[AWS Announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/02/ebs-multi-attach-available-provisioned-iops-ssd-volumes/):

> You can now enable Multi-Attach on Amazon EBS Provisioned IOPS io1 volumes to allow a single volume to be concurrently attached to up to sixteen AWS Nitro System-based Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances within the same Availability Zone.

Note that it's necessary to use file systems designed for multi-writing or replication like GFS2 or OCFS2.

Comment: Great improvement, but not available for `t2` instances that I'm using currently.
After they introduced Nitro I had a quick performance test in summer 2019 and my workload was slower by a factor of 2.5(!) on `t3` compared to `t2`. I did not do any analysis of the root cause yet.

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html, multi-attach is available only in the us-{east,west}-[12] and ap-northeast-2 Regions. I'm using eu-central-1, so I have to wait.

Comment: List of Nitro-System based instance types > https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances

Comment: GovCloud is not yet available either (my use case).

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do this. The EC2 API does not allow for it.

Comment: @Juergen, this is documented in the [EBS section of the EC2 faq](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#ebs): **Q: Do you support multiple instances accessing a single volume?**

*While you are able to attach multiple volumes to a single instance, attaching multiple instances to one volume is not supported at this time.*

Comment: Amazon added limited support for multiattach in Feb 2020 - see Dmitrii Narkevich's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this, use Elastic File System (EFS) rather than Elastic Block Storage (EBS).

https://aws.amazon.com/efs/

Notes:

1. It is much slower with small files

Comment: That has already been suggested in another answer, where I commented: 
EFS is file oriented, not block oriented. And S3 seems not useful for block storage (= mounting as a Linux block device).

Comment: And it is similar to a network drive in the fstab. Costs are high until realise you are not paying for unused capacity. For volatile needs it can be cheaper. Good for logs and archives or a staging area. (Semaphores and tokens as well if you are database averse).

Answer (score 2):

EBS is for a single instance only. Sharing an EBS instance would be like putting the same physical disk in two machines.

If you want two instances of the disk you can create an EBS snapshot or an AMI based on that EBS disk. This would let you run multiple instances of a web server, for example.

If you really want shared storage for data look at [Amazon EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/), or you could use S3.

Comment: EFS is file oriented, not block oriented. And S3 seems not useful for block storage (= mounting as a Linux block device), or is it ?

Comment: I think you're right, EFS and S3 are file storage not block storage, and that EBS is the only block store on Amazon. What are you actually trying to achieve? Multiple instances of the same server running?

Comment: Actually I wanted to use OCFS and Cluster LVM in a 3-node-cluster, which needs a shared SAN as its basis. Now it seems clear that cannot be done, not even using drbd as a SAN replacement, because drbd only allows two and not three mirrored disks. I'll be trying gluster instead.

Comment: You could perhaps consider setting up one of the EC2 instances as a file server?

Comment: That single non-clustered file server instance would be the single point of failure that I wanted to prevent from. That's why I asked for multiattach to support OCFS as filesystem in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by EEAA, you can not do that.

However, a workaround exists: attach the EBS volume to a single Linux instance, then export the device via iSCSI. Now on the "client" instances you simply had to attach the volume as a normal iSCSI drive.

Fot the sake of completeness: remember that traditional filesystems are **not** cluster aware. If you concurrently mount a disk from two iSCSI client, you will (more or less) instantly corrupt your filesystem (ext4 at least; xfs has some security safeguard that *should* prevent a double-mount). You **had** to use a cluster aware filesystem, as OCFS (as you suggested) or GFS2.

Comment: Using a singe "gateway" instance would destroy the cluster approach of preventing from a single point of failure. And if I had a multiattach feature, I would not only use it for a cluster filesystem, but also for Cluster LVM: Allocate a sufficiently large Block of several gigabytes from Amazon and suballocate (and free) smaller blocks to resize individual filesystems as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NFS independently of AWS. I remember using NFS back in the early 1990s as an excellent way to share a home directory volume across multiple SAMBA servers on DNS round robin. In my recent case, I am using several web servers to serve media and static data.

AWS simply don't provide sharing of the volume across multiple servers, which makes little sense because if you have two servers behind a load balancer, one file is only going to be accessed by one server at a time. Rackspace and Digital Ocean allow you to do this, but AWS frustraitingly does not unless you are in a particular zone.

I created an ELB volume, attached it to one server, then used NFS to attach it to the other server. Good instructions for doing this on Ubuntu are here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-20-04

**Update**
As pointed out by @Juergen, If the data is to be shared round robin on servers accessed by clients writing to the same area, an NFS share would not be a good idea, as the possibility of race conditions exists. For the example of round robin to web servers for media it works well though. AWS does provide multi-attacheable volumes if your AWS server is in a particular zone. Most AWS zones do not provide this service, and if your server has to be in one of those zones, you can't do it.

Comment: This question is about block storage for a cluster filesystem in order to prevent from a single point of failure. Using NFS does not help with that. And, as you can see in the accepted answer, AWS by now does provide sharing a volume across multiple servers, howver not on all machine types and not in all locations.

Comment: I did not read fears of "single point of failure" in the question, but yes, if you have one volume shared, that one volume could become corrupt or just die. I suspect AWS volumes are pretty robust tho, and use RAID or some other method of high availability.